# Remove the next letter after a specific character?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

So what i'm asking for is a thing that does as following:
I have this character: "&"
The following character could be anything, so it could look like this: &1, &2, &3, &4, &5, &6, &7, &8, &9, &0, &a, &b, &c, &d, &e,& &f, &r - How would I remove those without hardcoding it? Like if its &3 it would just remove it and if its &1 somewhere else it would remove that.

Comment: Please show the code of your own attempt and ask a more specific question, i.e. show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a very basic regular expression with a placeholder for any character (single character as I understand in this case).

```
System.out.println("&xx&y".replaceAll("&.", "")); // prints the middle "x" only
```

See API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed. I didn't know that I could use . to remove any character after a specific one, thank you.

Comment: @DanielHoller `replaceAll` takes regular expressions, so in addition to a dot you can use any regex pattern that you like.

Comment: `.` here does not match a newline.